# Global Search bar in modern experience document library

Tags: search, page-layout, modern-experience

With the new experience for a document library, we have a search box  that searches the document library.

Is it possible to put a search box in the header for global search?
[image]

Similar to the Classic Experience:
[image]

Comment: Did you happen to have any success? We were unable to achieve this so hid the quick launch nodes via css with the modern script editor webpart. <sub>[Not enough rep to comment; please change if better suited.]</sub>

Comment: Did you happen to have any success?
We were unable to achieve this so hid the quick launch nodes via css with the modern script editor webpart. - @Declan Turner